# Drawing a straight line with Pinta

Tags: png, xfig, pinta

I'm trying to superimpose a straight line onto a .png image. [GIMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP) is notoriously impossible to use for simple things, so people have suggested [Pinta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinta_%28software%29).

However, as far as I can tell, the only lines you can draw with this program are freeform ones, i.e., there doesn't appear to be anything like a ruler tool. How can I draw a straight line?

Or is there another program that does it? Again, I need to be super-imposing on an existing .png file, so [Xfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfig) won't work.

Comment: With the tool `Line/curve`

Comment: Alternative program: `mtpaint`

Comment: Thanks very much!    mtpaint looks as though it will work.    Wish the documentation were a bit easier to deal with.    The handbook looks thorough but, for example, it's hard to find information on the simple stuff like here's how do draw a line, change the linewidth and set the color.     But I'll figure it out, hopefully

Comment: Re pinta, I've been looking everywhere for a Line/curve tool and am for some reason unable to find it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easy: use Pinta's Line/Curve tool.  In the screenshot below, my mouse pointer is over the icon for this tool:

[image]

When you first run Pinta, the Tools area might be narrow and so you might not see this icon.  If you **widen the Tools area** then you will see it.

Comment: This works as expected.   However, my goal is to super-impose lines on an imported graphic.     Whenever I try to do that, the program crashes with this message `=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application`      Can you advise how to import a graphic,  and draw over it, without the program crashing?     Thanks very much!   Leo

Comment: @LeoSimon: What operating system are you running?  What version of Mono?  What version of Pinta?

Comment: @AdomDingle, I'm running ubuntu 18.04, with pinta 1.6 and mono 4.6.2, though I didn't know that mono was involved.   I'm certainly not calling it explictly, maybe pinta does?

Comment: @LeoSimon: Yes, Pinta is a Mono application.  I would upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, the new LTS release.  I'm running that release, and I just ran Pinta, dragged in a JPG image, drew a few lines and saved the image, and it worked with no crash.

Comment: @AdamDingle why is this called line/curve tool, if it only draws curves? I could not create a line consisting of several segments where the corners would not be rounded.

Comment: Oh, I see, I can right-click the node, and straighten it, but that's a bit impractical to do this individually with all the nodes. But ok, at least some way to get the result is there.